# About JSON string (URL encoding) of android-webview

Tags: android, json, webview, android-webview

**In the old version of Webview, the expected operation was achieved by the following processing.**

```
    internal fun openURL(json: String) {
        try {
            val jsonData = JSONObject(json)
```

> WebView Ver：80.0.3987.99
>
> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(205)] "WebviewToNative API executed:
> {"methodname":"openInBrowser","params":{"url":"https:// ..(omitted)..
> /init?registid=8og02vdtjmr38ap09hdurk6a2u","backurl":"/"}}", source:
> https:// ..(omitted).. /resources/js/native.js?ver=0001

**The following error will occur in the new version of Webview for the same string.**

> WebView Ver：94.0.4606.71
>
> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at character
> 167 of {"url":"https:// ..(omitted)..
> /init?registid=epqnn5m4ufveh25tfl25stgp1%22,%22backurl%22:%22/%22}

**I have two questions.**

1. What was the fix in Webview for the difference in behavior?
2. I have confirmed that the following correction code works as expected, but is there any problem?

```
    internal fun openURL(json: String) {
        try {
            val encoding = "UTF-8"
            val decodeJsonStr = URLDecoder.decode(json, encoding);

            val jsonData = JSONObject(decodeJsonStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a new bug introduced in `URLDecoder`, as `"` character at the end of URL even after `decode` call is still partially HTML-URL-encoded (closing `"` is encoded as `%22` in here: `...init?registid=...tgp1%22,%22backurl...`)

I would recommend to try some lib for parsing JSON, they are mostly more efficient that built-in `JSONObject`. take a look at [`gson`](https://github.com/google/gson) or [`Jackson`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)